# Xamarin.Forms Tap Gesturer not responding

Tags: xamarin.forms, gestures

In my XAML I have:

```
<Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" TextColor="Blue">
   <Label.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding URL}" />
   </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

In the view model (and I've checked the binding context) I have

```
private ICommand tapCommand;
public ICommand TapCommand
{
    get { return tapCommand; }
}

public LinkReportPageViewModel()
{
    PopulateLinkReport();
    tapCommand = new Command( OnTapped );
}

public void OnTapped( object tappedURL )
{
    Log.LogThis( $"Tapped on {tappedURL}", "LinkReportPageVM", DateTime.Now );
}
```

I expect that when I tap on the label I'll hit a breakpoint in OnTapped, but I don't. Am I missing something?

Note, this label is in a grouped list.

This was based on https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/

Thanks!!

Comment: Is your label in a nested stackLayout?

Comment: Your code looks fine, but what really matters here is the context where you have your Command property. If the label is inside a list, then the BindingContext for each item is the list item itself, not the parent context (the binding context is inherited from the parents by default). Please, post your ListView xaml code (only what matters to your question) and I'll give you a appropriated answer =)

Answer (score 2):

As Diego mentioned, the binding context for the label is the model of the data item that the ListView is bound to. Try changing it to this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" TextColor="Blue">
   <Label.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TapCommand, Source={x:Reference NameOfListView}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding URL}" />
   </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Also ensure that you give your ListView an x:Name

We are telling the command that it's binding context is the parent ListView, which is bound to the ViewModel containing your command.